# AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am fairly new to PySpark. I am getting an attribute error while trying to run a logistic regression. I am trying to run a logistic regression on minmaxscaler vectors to get the probability values of a likely match up between the data points.

```
number_games = df2.filter(df2.GAME_ID > 22000000).filter(
    df2.GAME_ID < 40000000).groupby("TEAM_ABBREVIATION").agg(
    (F.sum("FGM") / F.countDistinct("GAME_ID")).alias('Points_Per_Game'))

vectorassembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["Points_Per_Game"],
                                  outputCol="Performance")
scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="Performance", outputCol="Output")

vectors = vectorassembler.transform(number_games)
scaler_model = scaler.fit(vectors)
scaler_data = scaler_model.transform(vectors)
statistics_teams = scaler_data.select('TEAM_ABBREVIATION',
                                      'Output')  # teams match up against one another
statistics_teams

RDD2 = sc.parallelize(statistics_teams.collect())
# RDD4 = RDD2.map( lambda x: x.split()) even as a pipelineRDD I get the same attribute error

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.001)
logistic_model = lr.fit(RDD2)

logistic_model.show()
```

the error returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-3c0eb05824a8> in <module>
      1 lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.001)
----> 2 logistic_model = lr.fit(RDD4)
      3 
      4 logistic_model.show()

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 335         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    336         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    337         return self._copyValues(model)

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    330         """
    331         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 332         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):

AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Comment: no need to convert to rdd. just call it as `lr.fit(statistics_teams)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to call `.fit()` on the actual data frame, in this case `statistics_teams`? I think that LogisticRegression works with data frames and not RDDs.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I get an error: IllegalArgumentException: features does not exist. Available: TEAM_ABBREVIATION, Output which are the columns of the dataframe

Comment: This is a different problem though. You should create a different question for this.